# Git rebase child branch

Tags: git

My git folder structure is like,

master ----- development ----- sprint1 ----- myfolder

I want to rebase the child branch 'myfolder' from sprint1, so that I can get the latest code from sprint1 to 'myfolder'.

What are the commands to do rebase?

Comment: You want to rebase `myfolder` onto `sprint1`? Whilst you have `myfolder` checked out, run `rebase sprint1`

Comment: From your "drawing" there, it would seem it is already rebased since `myfolder` is already a child of `sprint1`. Otherwise, apply what @OliverRadini mentions. Finally, branches != folders.

Comment: No, I want to rebase sprint1 onto myfolder

Comment: So you want `master---development---myfolder---sprint1`? For that, you could use `git rebase --onto development sprint1 myfolder` and *after that*, `git rebase myfolder sprint1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing folders with branches but I think I get the point.

First check out myfolder

```
git checkout myfolder
```

Then rebase all changes from sprint1 onto myfolder

```
git rebase sprint1
```

You can do it in one go from any branch

```
git rebase sprint1 myfolder
```

All of this (and more) can be found in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: I want to rebase sprint1 to myfolder. (myfolder is the child of sprint1)

Comment: According to the drawing in the questions, these commands will be no-ops. (If the drawing is not accurate, this is of course the correct answer)

Comment: My guess is that the drawing is wrong. If it's correct it's already rebased and there would be no question ...